Remove selected span in Woocommerce Customer Emails
I’m new to PHP and also new to WooCommerce. I would like to remove the meta in red, but it is actually a span in the email.


I've tried adding this code to modify email CSS, but is there a way to just target the concerned text?
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_styles', 'add_css_to_emails', 10, 2 );
function add_css_to_emails( $css, $email ) {
$css .= '
    td:first-child{font-size: 0px }
';
return $css;
}



    add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_styles', 'add_css_to_emails', 10, 2 );
function add_css_to_emails( $css, $email ) {
$css .= '
    td:first-child span{font-size: 0px }
';
return $css;
}


We'd have to see the HTML to be able to say for sure, but using td:first-child to select only the first cell in each row might already do the trick.

@CBroe , Hi sir, using td: first-child removed both the product name and the preorder date. Is there way to specify/just filter the pre-order date? Thank you

I meant using td:first-child in place of the td in the selector your already had to target the span elements, not replacing the whole thing ...

Add the below code snippet in your active theme's functions.php in order to hide order item meta within email template.
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', function() {
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_display_item_meta', '__return_empty_string' );
} );


WooCommerce uses template files to generate customer emails. You'll need to find the template file responsible for the specific email you want to customize. In this case, it looks like you want to customize the order details table in the email.
Plugins\woocommerce\templates\emails\email-order-details.php file

Please check above file
Once you've located the template file, copy it to your theme's folder or child theme's folder. This ensures that your changes won't be overridden when WooCommerce or your theme is updated.
I hope it will help you someone..!
